# How to detect if QDialog.exec() is active

Tags: qt

Is there a way to detect whether execution is currently in the middle of QDialog.exec()?

I'm the author of DreamPie, a Python shell, and it lets you run Python code while Qt GUI is being displayed. It does that by running the Qt event loop for 1/10 of a second, and then checking if any Python commands need to be executed. The event loop is stopped by a QTimer which calls QApplication.quit() after the timeout.

If a QDialog.exec() is active, however, I don't want to call QApplication.quit(), because it will break the code. The current solution is to check whether there's a modal dialog active, by checking if QApplication.activeModalWidget() is None. However, I currently have a modal dialog which is not run with QDialog.exec(), and it's blocking Python commands for no reason.

Is there a way to exit the event loop only if it's not called recursively by QDialog.exec()?

Thanks!

Comment: you can block the event loop by simply executing the python in the QTimer

Comment: Does your dialog have reject/accept buttons or only informative "OK"? If there is only OK button that is "accept" button for your dialog than you can check if result was changed to accepted.

Comment: ratchet freak: Indeed I can, but it will mean a big refactoring of the code, as it has to work with no Qt installed.

Comment: Kamil Klimek: It's the user's dialog, which can be anything. DreamPie lets you run any Python code.

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether your dialog is visible with `QDialog.isVisible`. Normally, a modal dialog is visible only while it is being executed.

Comment: Thanks. However, I happen to have a dialog which is modal and visible, but is not run with exec() so there's no problem with running other Python code while it is visible.